# vertical align checkboxes generated by jquery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

How do I get the checkboxes to align vertically?

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/8uuv6/).

I want

```
[] Full Feed
[] Trip Feed
[] Flight Feed
```

This appears to be simple but i've tried `"vertical-align:middle;"` in several positions.

Optimally I would like set the alignment somewhere here:

```
$.each(myjson, function (i, v) {
    var feedname = this.name
        $("#calsubscribe").append($("<label>").text(this.name).prepend(
            $("<input>").attr({
                'type': 'checkbox', 
                'class' : 'inp-checkbox', 
                'name':'subscribecal',
                "data-feed": feedname,
                "style":'vertical-align:middle;'
            }).val(this.id)
               .prop('checked', this.checked)
        ));
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: `#calsubscribe label {
  display: block;
}`...? http://jsfiddle.net/8uuv6/39/

Comment: nice that works!

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simply just `...$("<br><input>").attr({...`

Checkout [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8uuv6/40/)

Comment: this is even shorter and solves the problem in the desired code block. Thanks I will use this.

Comment: @AndreElrico Good luck

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can set the `label` elements to appear at block level within their container using CSS:

```css
#calsubscribe label { 
  display: block; 
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8uuv6/39/)

Comment: Problem is that the label takes all available width of parent, meaning if you click outside of label's text, you still click the label. It could be quite disturbing regarding UX